# Swipe right on second view does not work once I enter the third view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have multiple navigation controllers in my storyboard which handle the back buttons. I also have a swipe method

```
- (void)swipedScreenRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipeGesture
{
    NSLog(@"swipedScreenRight");
    [masterViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

From the first view to the second view I can swipedScreenRight and the view slides back to the first view. I go from the first, to one of the three views on the third level of the navigation, I can press back or swipedScreenRight and return to the second view. I cannot swipe back to the first view, I can only press back. How can I make it swipe from the second view after visiting the third?

Comment: If you want to jump back to the root of your navigation controller you can always use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`, otherwise you could exploit unwind segues.

Comment: I don't want to pop to root when I swipe back. I don't know how to exploit unwind segues.

Comment: You might want to check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them